# How does one linearly interpolate two equations?

Tags: interpolation

Was looking at this video https://youtu.be/60VoL-F-jIQ?t=213 and a linear interpolation between two equations is mentioned. I don't understand how one linearly interpolates two equations. The video shows the following 2 equations and a 3rd one which is said to be the linear interpolation of the first two.

1. $$a(x) = x^2$$
2. $$b(x) = -(x-1)^2 + 1$$
3. $$ c(x) = a(x)\cdot(1-x) + b(x) \cdot x$$

I don't understand how equation 3 was reached from equations 1 and 2?

Comment: The idea is that $c(x)$ is a function that behaves more or less like one function at one endpoint, and more or less like the other function at the other endpoint. Notice how $c(0)=a(0)$ and $c(1)=b(1)$. For values of $x$ close to $0$, the interpolating function $c(x)$ will more closely resemble $a(x)$; for values of $x$ close to $1$, $c(x)$ will look more like $b(x)$.

Comment: It's simply a definition: there is nothing to understand. The interpolation of two functions $a(x), b(x)$ is defined as $$a(x) \cdot (1-x) + b(x) \cdot x$$

Comment: Seems similar to $a(x) (1-\lambda) +b(x)\lambda$ for $\lambda \in (0,1)$. Though it's just a definition as pointed @Crostul

Comment: I was starting feel like I was not good enough for not being able to derive the equation, but if it's just a definition, then ok. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume a(x),b(x) corresponds to N1,N2 respectively.
Also if in the interpolation we use ξ instead of x below you can see the interpolation between the 2 functions which is nothing else than interpolation between 2 numbers actually along ξ[0,1].
[image]